# Vue Page doesn't scroll down upon loading

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, vue.js, dom

i'm having difficulty trying to make the page scroll down to the latest message upon load. I have the same function that is working when a person sends a new message and the page will scroll down straight to the latest message upon sending.
I've tried a few methods like scrollIntoView and even setting the scrollTop to 9999. However, when i console log the scrollTop, it still indicates that it is 0. The function is called in mounted after the messages are loaded in created.
Anyone able to assist me why its not working? Really appreciate the help, thank you.

````
<v-container>
  <div id="top-nav">
    <v-avatar id="avatar">
      <img src="../../public/img/icons/myavatar.png" alt="avatar">
    </v-avatar>
    <div id="title-grp">
      <h3 id="sofia-title">Sofia</h3>
      <div id="online-grp">
        <span id="online-circle"></span>
        <p id="online-text">Online</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="msg-container">
    <v-row dense>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-card
          style="width: fit-content"
          v-for="(message,index) in messages"
          :key="index"
          :style="{'margin-left': message.isRobot ? '' : 'auto'}"
          :color="message.isRobot? '#F5F3FF' :'#C66BCC'" 
          id="convo-space"
        >
          <p id="timestamp" :style="{'color': message.isRobot? '#808080' : '#000000'}">{{message.timestamp}}</p>
          <v-card-text
            :style="{'color': message.isRobot ? 'black' : 'white', 'font-size': '16px'}"
          >
            {{message.text}}
          </v-card-text>

        </v-card>
        <div id="bottom-scroll" ref="last-message"></div>   
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>    

  <div id="bottom-container">
    <div class="col-text">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type here" id="text-input" v-model="userMessage">
    </div>
    <div class="col-btn">
      <button @click="sendMessage" id="btn-color-text"> Send </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</v-container>
        

</template>

<script>

  import {config} from "../config.js"
  const token = config.dialogflow.clientBot;

  import { ApiAiClient } from 'api-ai-javascript';
  const client = new ApiAiClient({accessToken: token});

  import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

  import firebase from "firebase";

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      messages: [],
      userMessage: "", 
    }),
    methods: {
      sendMessage(){
        var timestamp = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'});
        const usrMessage = {
          text: this.userMessage,
          isRobot: false,
          timestamp: timestamp
        };

        this.messages.push(usrMessage);

        client.textRequest(this.userMessage).then((response) => {
          const robotMessage = {
            text: response.result.fulfillment.speech,
            isRobot: true,
            timestamp: timestamp
          };

          firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("users")
          .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
          .collection("messages")
          .add({
            userMessage: usrMessage.text,
            robotMessage: robotMessage.text,
            timestamp: timestamp 
          });

          const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res,ms));

          const pushMsg = async () => {
            let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8000);
            await delay(randNum);
            await this.messages.push(robotMessage);
            this.scrollToEnd();
          };

          pushMsg();
          this.scrollToEnd();
        });
          


        this.userMessage = "";
        console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
      },
      scrollToEnd(){
        var container = this.$el.querySelector('#msg-container');
        container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
        console.log(container.scrollHeight);
        console.log(container.scrollTop);
      }
    },

    created(){
      var oldMessages = [];

      firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .collection("messages")
      .get()
      .then( (querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
          var snapMsg = doc.data();
          let robot = {
            text: snapMsg.robotMessage,
            timestamp: snapMsg.timestamp,
            isRobot: true
          }

          let human = {
            text: snapMsg.userMessage,
            timestamp: snapMsg.timestamp,
            isRobot: false
          }
          
          oldMessages.unshift(human, robot);
          });
          this.messages = oldMessages;
          });
    },
    mounted(){
      var bottomDiv = this.$el.querySelector('#bottom-scroll');
      bottomDiv.scrollIntoView();
      console.log(bottomDiv);
      console.log(bottomDiv.scrollIntoView());

      // var bottomDiv = this.$el.querySelector('#msg-container');
      // bottomDiv.scrollTop = 9999;      
      // console.log(bottomDiv.scrollTop);

      navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
        console.log('Push Notification received');
        console.log(e.data.firebaseMessagingData.notification.body);
        var timestamp = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(undefined, {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'});
        const robotMessage = {
          text: e.data.firebaseMessagingData.notification.body,
          isRobot: true,
          timestamp: timestamp
        }
        firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection("messages")
        .add({
          robotMessage: robotMessage.text,
          timestamp: robotMessage.timestamp
        });

        this.messages.push(robotMessage);
      });
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        user: "user"
      })
    }
  }
</script> ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that you are trying to update UI when the data has been updated and the DOM has not been updated. Call the `scrollToEnd` when the Dom/Ui has been updated using nextTick, vue nextTick is called whenever the DOM has updated

For example Your code

```
const pushMsg = async () => {
        let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8000);
        await delay(randNum);
        await this.messages.push(robotMessage);
        this.scrollToEnd();
      };
```

should be

```
 let self= this;
 const pushMsg = async () => {
        let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8000);
        await delay(randNum);
        await this.messages.push(robotMessage);
  self.$nextTick(function(){
   this.scrollToEnd();
  })
        
      };
```

Comment: Hey Emmanuel, thanks for the answer. I've tried to implement what you suggest but it still doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: check https://github.com/ogomaemmanuel/VueChatApp/blob/master/ClientApp/components/MessageBox/MessageBox.vue

Comment: thanks man. It seems to work now. I implemented the nextTick in mounted but it didn't work. So i saw your code that you placed the nextTick in watched and finally it worked. Thanks @emmanuel !

Comment: @AhmadNurhadi you are welcome, kindly upvote it as the answer